# WPF using view inside mainwindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I am trying to use a view inside my mainwinow. So I created the view inside the view folder in my project and try to use it in the main window. But I get run time error. Can anyone help?

XAML MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="DataRetrieval.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:DataRetrieval.Views"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TabControl Name="TabControl1" >
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TabItem Header="General">
            <views:Login></views:Login>
        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

XAML View:

```
<Window x:Class="DataRetrieval.Views.Login"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Login" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>


        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <Label Content="User Name:" Width="Auto"/>
            <Label Content="Password:" Width="Auto"/>

        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="Username"  Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"/>
            <PasswordBox Grid.Column="1" Name="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"/>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But when I run the application, I get a runtime error on my mainwindow xaml code:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content' threw an exception.' Line number '14' and line position '14'.
```

Comment: you cant nest a window in another window. You should take the grid only, without the window around it

Comment: if you need it in another file create a UserControl instead

Comment: you need to create separate usercontrol and use it in main window.

Comment: Thanks @Dominik, usercontrol instead of window was the answer.

Comment: Change the second window to user control.Then it will work

Comment: @user3033921 I added it as answer so that the question can be resolved properly ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot nest a `Window` in another `Window`. You can either put the `Grid` directly in the `Window` or create a `UserControl` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Change the second window to user control.Then it will work

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to embed it in a frame:

```
<Frame  Source="Login.xaml" />
```

instead of

```
<views:Login></views:Login>
```

You might need to make the Login.xaml Window a Page though.

I'm sure there are better ways to achieve it, but it works=)

Comment: yap. Frame is also better option when we do  navigation by  window to window